# Grub Rescue upon attempting to reinstall WIndows 8.1 on Msata

Tags: windows-8.1, partitioning, grub, mbr, gpt

I had a new device and not dual boot as far as I am aware.

The new clean install of Windows 8.1 was compromised.

Intel provided a new device.

Upon attempting to reinstall Windows 8.1, it would not allow installation onto the Msata stating it was MBR and GPT was required.

Followed instructions to convert to GPT.

That resulted in a remaining partition on the Msata with unallocated space and that could not be removed.

Upon attempting to install 8.1, it then stated my product key was invalid and then when rebooting, grub rescue screen prevailed.

BIOS is accessible.

The Windows 8.1 installation media was corrupted.

Rufus was required to reformat the USB media and I have questions about what files that reformatting wrote to it. Should it be blank afterwards?

I have not yet made  new installation USB media.

Output from grub rescue "ls" command is : (hd0) (hd0, msdos1) (hd1)

I believe (hd1) is the SSD which is accessible, using my external jump type of USB adapter upon removing it, and appears uncorrupted

I am of the belief that hd0 is the grub'd Msata with the partition containing unallocated space.

The Msata's manufacturer provides no formatting tools for it.

I have no means to access it outside of the device.

What should I do in order to get a clean install of Windows 8.1? I am not interested in making it dual boot at this time.

Comment: Thanks for simply voting it down and not even pointing me to a link which you know to be relevant. I've researched all over the net and this site. I am not a grub recovery or linux expert, I'm just a guy trying to get some help in order to be able to use a device I truly need to be working. Maybe you guys voting it down are the one that compromised it leaving behind your encryption algorithm for your several machine keys?

Comment: If you aren't interested in dual booting, there is probably no reason to keep grub here. Perhaps it's best to clean the disk and start again. You could use something like `DBAN` to wipe the disk, then maybe the Windows Installer will be nice to you and let you install to the cleaned drive.

Comment: I have it running on ubunto. Odd I could see the SDD and Msata when using the live disk. After installing it, I've no idea why it doesn't offer me a view of the machine's drives. Guess I'll have to dig and see if I need some su or root permission to do so. It's been a while since I ran a linux machine. Once done and I know more about the how to's and wherefore's, then I'll see about dual booting it with Windows. Can you recommend a link you feel is timely and effective. No shortage of info to wade through.......thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;
Backup all important data from the disk or partition (if you make 2 or more drive from 1 hard disk, ex drive C and drive D)
Boot from your installation media, do not choose install now, but choose repair your computer, after that choose advanced option, choose command prompt.
Type "diskpart" at command prompt then hit enter.
Type "list disk" then hit enter.
Type "select disk (number of disk that you want to install Windows)" ex: "select disk 0" hit enter.
Type "clean" hit enter (this will erase entire disk including all partition, so it's important to backup your data before doing this)
type "exit", hit enter to come out from diskpart, type "exit" again and hit enter to come out from command prompt.
Restart your computer and boot again from your installation media, now choose "install now" to make clean installation of windows 8.1.
Continue with installation progress.

For your information, installation media specially using USB stick will be corrupted if you turn off or reset the computer while the USB stick is still in use by installation progress.

Comment: The install media, which worked fine prior, had not been handled as described. I'm more inclined to believe whatever was installed on the Msata, while Win8.1 was up and running, was nefarious.

Comment: The install media, which worked fine prior, had not been mishandled as described. I'm more inclined to believe whatever remains installed on the Msata, while Win8.1 was up and running, is nefarious. I made a Unbunto Live USB while waiting for any answer. I know virtually nothing about it or partitioning or formatting and wonder if using it before attempting to reinstall windows would be a better plan. If so, I would welcome a link or instructions about what exact steps I should take. The odd thing is the install media was not product key specific. My product key is $199 bucks valid.

Comment: I was going to make a Hirens BCD but the instructions for it are sketchy starting from specifying formatting FAT. My devices do not offer that option and from there, what I downloaded in the latest version is not congruent with the step by step shown on Hiren's site. Regardless, I was unsuccessful in making one that would work.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This seems like a reasonable way to get rid of anything on the drive and start again. I don't think they are suggesting you mishandled it, just that it may become corrupted if you do.

Comment: Tough crowd? I'd prefer not subjecting my windows installation to whatever is on it. I haven't tried the Ubunto Live on it yet but would like instructions as to what should be done assuming it will boot. It is a UEFI machine if that matters.